# Erratic running with smell of gasoline, then dies

Tags: ford, fuel-system, stall, fusion

Spits sputter smell of gasoline when it happened and then dies. Restart car and does same. Check engine light is on now. 2013 Ford Fusion Turbo SE 2.0L  Ecoboost 76,000 miles. While idle it starts to sputter and smell gasoline inside car. It will start to die and if give it acceleration runs rough and will just die

Comment: Is there any visible fuel leak in the engine compartment?

Comment: Have you read the engine codes?